# Merge parts of two different strings into new string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three columns `PRODUCTID`, `PRODUCTNAME`, `PRODUCTCODE` within a table.
I wish to insert a new product creating the `PRODUCTID` from the other columns

How do I take the first two letters of `PRODUCTNAME` and the last four numbers of `PRODUCTCODE` and populate them into `PRODUCTID`?

I do not want a product to be duplicated within the table and if attempted I want the table to remain unchanged. The default `PRODUCTID` is `DEFAULT`.

I have so far got:

```
INSERT INTO `v1_products` (`PRODUCTNAME`, `PRODUCTNUMBER`) VALUES ("EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLE4444");

UPDATE `v1_products`

SET `PRODUCTID`=(SELECT CONCAT(
    (SELECT LEFT(`PRODUCTNAME`,2)) , (SELECT RIGHT(`PRODUCTNUMBER`,4))))

WHERE `PRODUCTID`= "DEFALT" AND `PRODUCTID`!=`PRODUCTID`

LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What exactly is happening now? And what were you trying to accomplish with this filter `WHERE PRODUCTID= "DEFALT" AND PRODUCTID!=PRODUCTID`?

Comment: What do you want to do, `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?  ``PRODUCTID`!=`PRODUCTID`` is meaningless as there is only one table referenced, so `PRODUCTID` always equals `PRODUCTID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I would reccomend setting the `PRODUCTID` column to be unique. This will prevent any products from having the same values. If your default PRODUCTID is "default" then you may need to do this after updating the ids.

Your `UPDATE` statement is fine except from the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE `PRODUCTID`= "DEFALT" AND `PRODUCTID`!=`PRODUCTID`
```

There's a typo in `"DEFAULT"` and

```
`PRODUCTID`!=`PRODUCTID`
```

Will never be true.

```
WHERE `PRODUCTID`= "DEFAULT"
```

Should be enough.

The above will fix existing products with incorrect ids. Now you should change your insert so that `PRODUCTID` is set correctly for each new product. You can do this by simply adding the `CONCAT` you used in the update statement:

```
INSERT INTO `v1_products` (`PRODUCTID`, `PRODUCTNAME`, `PRODUCTNUMBER`) 
VALUES (
    CONCAT(
        LEFT("EXAMPLE",2),
        RIGHT("EXAMPLE4444",4)),
    "EXAMPLE",
    "EXAMPLE4444");
```

From the discussion in the comments an example of only setting the columns values once:

```
INSERT INTO v1_products (PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTNUMBER,PRODUCTID) 
VALUES ( 
    "EXAMPLE", 
    "EXAMPLE4444",
    CONCAT( LEFT(PRODUCTNAME,2), RIGHT(PRODUCTNUMBER,4)));
```

Comment: I have made the column UNIQUE and get an error when the product is entered for a second time (BRILLIANT). However a record with the DEFAULT value is entered into the table (I don't want this to happen). Help please

Comment: Do you mean that if you try and enter a product with a duplicate product id it creates one with `DEFAULT`? This shouldn't be the case. What does your insert look like?

Comment: My INSERT is shown in the question. I believe because my INSERT statement is done first it creates the record with default, when really all I want is to create a record complete with its calculated product code. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @jbw Whoops. Missed that. I'll add an updated INSERT into my answer.

Comment: Is there any way of doing it by using the column name in the CONCAT rather than using the "EXAMPLE" (Quotation marks), When I try I get the following error: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: INSERT INTO `v1_products` (`PRODUCTID`, `PRODUCTNAME`, `PRODUCTNUMBER`) 
VALUES (
    CONCAT(
        LEFT(`PRODUCTNAME`,2),
        RIGHT(`PRODUCTNUMBER`,4),
    "EXAMPLE",
    "EXAMPLE4444"))

Comment: @jbw Not that I know of. `PRODUCTNAME` and `PRODUCTNUMBER` aren't set so there's nothing to refer to.

Comment: @jbw Actually I stand corrected. You can use: `INSERT INTO v1_products 
(PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTNUMBER,PRODUCTID) 
VALUES ( "EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLE4444",CONCAT( LEFT(PRODUCTNAME,2), RIGHT(PRODUCTNUMBER,4)));`

Comment: I just amended it while waiting for your answer, and and got it to work the same way, thanks for the help!